# Is there a maximum number of remote connections that can be setup on mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini, osx-server

We have a mac mini running OSx 10.9.4 with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 and 8 GB. We use this as a "server" so people within the company can remotely place files that need to be uploaded onto our DAM system. We are now getting a message that says "No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept". Can you tell me if the number of connections can be changed or is there a set limit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What client is showing that error message? Do you have a date/time stamp of when it happens and can look at the system.log file for the server at the same time?

Comment: This article may help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6452612 - says in 10.9 smb which is the first type of connection that will be tried is set at 100 connections. If smb is not accepted, afp will be tried after but that connection on that is unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help, but I would update 10.9.4 to 10.9.5 as I found 10.9.4 to have a few issues on the servers and Mac I service for clients.

Note: I can't think of any compatibility issues that would be an issues with that update, but assess the software used before you update of course.